# IdThreadComponent messes the User interface

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ftp

I am using the IdThreadComponent to perform a simple ftp upload to a server.

The code to the ftp upload is as follows :

```
procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdThreadComponent1Run(
  Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);

begin
  IdFtp1.Host := 'ip';
  IdFtp1.Username := 'user';
  IdFtp1.Password := 'pass';
  try
    IdFtp1.Connect;
  except
    begin
      msgDlgBox.MessageDlg('Could not connect!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      publishing := false;
    end;
  end;
  IdFtp1.Put(txtPath.text, file_name);
  IdFtp1.Quit;
  IdFtp1.Disconnect;
End;
```

The FtpWorkEnd is as follows :

```
procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdFTP1WorkEnd(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
var
  Params : TStringList;
  Resp : String;
begin
  IdThreadComponent1.Active := false;
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  Params.Add('enotice_publish='+packet);
  if (aborted = true) then
  begin
    IdFtp1.Quit;
    idFtp1.Disconnect;
    aborted := false;
    uploadGauge.Value := 0;
    uploadGauge.Visible := false;
    frmNoticeWindow.Height := 512;
    btnUpload.Caption := 'Publish';
    exit;
  end;
  Resp := doPost('url', params);
  if (Resp = 'Notice published successfully!') then
    msgDlgBox.MessageDlg(Resp, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0)
  else
    msgDlgBox.MessageDlg(Resp, mtError, [mbOk], 0);

    frmNoticeWindow.Refresh;

  uploadGauge.Value := 0;
  uploadGauge.Visible := false;
  frmNoticeWindow.Height := 512;
  btnUpload.Caption := 'Publish';
  publishing := false;
  txtPath.Text := '';
  txtNoticeHeader.Text := '';
end;
```

When the upload is completed, the http post is made and in response I get a string [Success/Failure] from the server.

The problem is, after this MessageDlg, the components of my app, turns in to white blocks and the app's controls can no longer be used.

I did try an update() on the form, but that didn't help.

I'm using Business Skin Forms to skin my app, and the thread component is messing the form after closing.

Comment: You have to do all the UI work on the UI thread

Comment: Please don't put tag information into the title. You've added the delphi tag; there's no need to duplicate it in the title, and [] in the tile area have specific meaning here. Thanks.

Comment: ok @KenWhite. After I stop the idThreadComponent, I am supposed to be in the main thread, right ? If not where do I put mu UI related code ?

Comment: No, you are NOT in the main UI thread.  `OnWorkEnd` runs in the same thread as `TIdFTP`, and that is being used in a worker thread.  So you must synchronize with the main thread in order to access the UI safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TIdThreadComponent.OnRun` event handler runs in the context of a worker thread, not in the main UI thread.  All of your `TIdFTP` operations are running in the context of the worker thread, which is fine.  However, your `TIdFTP.OnWorkEnd` event handler is trying to make UI updates, but it is running in the worker thread as well, not in the main UI thread.  That is not safe.  You MUST synchronize with the main UI thread in order to access the UI safely.  That includes calls to `MessageDlg()`, which is not a thread-safe function.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdThreadComponent1Run(
  Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
begin
  IdFtp1.Host := 'ip';
  IdFtp1.Username := 'user';
  IdFtp1.Password := 'pass';
  if aborted then Exit;
  try
    IdFtp1.Connect;
  except
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        msgDlgBox.MessageDlg('Could not connect!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
      end
    );
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    if not aborted then
      IdFtp1.Put(txtPath.text, file_name);
  finally
    IdFtp1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdThreadComponent1AfterRun(
  Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
begin
  publishing := false;
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      uploadGauge.Value := 0;
      uploadGauge.Visible := false;
      frmNoticeWindow.Height := 512;
      btnUpload.Caption := 'Publish';
      if not aborted then
      begin
        txtPath.Text := '';
        txtNoticeHeader.Text := '';
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdFTP1Work(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  if aborted then
    IdFtp1.Abort;
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdFTP1WorkEnd(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
var
  Params : TStringList;
  Resp : String;
begin
  if aborted then Exit;
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('enotice_publish='+packet);
    Resp := doPost('url', params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      if (Resp = 'Notice published successfully!') then
        msgDlgBox.MessageDlg(Resp, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0)
      else
        msgDlgBox.MessageDlg(Resp, mtError, [mbOk], 0);    
    end
  );
end;
```

If you are using a version of Delphi that does not support anonymous procedures, you can replace `TThread.Queue()` with `TIdNotify` instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.MsgBoxCouldNotConnect;
begin
  msgDlgBox.MessageDlg('Could not connect!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.MsgBoxPostOk;
begin
  msgDlgBox.MessageDlg('Notice published successfully!', mtInformation, [mbOk], 0)
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.MsgBoxPostFail;
begin
  msgDlgBox.MessageDlg('Notice failed to publish!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);    
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.ResetUiOk;
begin
  uploadGauge.Value := 0;
  uploadGauge.Visible := false;
  frmNoticeWindow.Height := 512;
  btnUpload.Caption := 'Publish';
  txtPath.Text := '';
  txtNoticeHeader.Text := '';
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.ResetUiAborted;
begin
  uploadGauge.Value := 0;
  uploadGauge.Visible := false;
  frmNoticeWindow.Height := 512;
  btnUpload.Caption := 'Publish';
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdThreadComponent1Run(
  Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
begin
  IdFtp1.Host := 'ip';
  IdFtp1.Username := 'user';
  IdFtp1.Password := 'pass';
  if aborted then Exit;
  try
    IdFtp1.Connect;
  except
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(MsgBoxCouldNotConnect);
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    if not aborted then
      IdFtp1.Put(txtPath.text, file_name);
  finally
    IdFtp1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdThreadComponent1AfterRun(
  Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
begin
  publishing := false;
  if aborted then
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ResetUiAborted)
  else
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ResetUiOk);
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdFTP1Work(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  if aborted then
    IdFtp1.Abort;
end;

procedure TfrmNoticeWindow.IdFTP1WorkEnd(Sender: TObject;
  AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
var
  Params : TStringList;
  Resp : String;
begin
  if aborted then Exit;
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('enotice_publish='+packet);
    Resp := doPost('url', params);
    if (Resp = 'Notice published successfully!') then
      TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(MsgBoxPostOk)
    else
      TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(MsgBoxPostFail);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am using Delphi 7 and TIdNotify also given as error, "Undeclared Identifier : TIdNotifier"

Comment: I upgraded my project to Delphi 2009 and the Queue works now. But when I am running the program in IDE, in closing the app, I am getting a "Assertion Failure(!SetThreadContextFailed) error and I have to force close delphi and restart for it to work again.

Comment: `TIdNotify` (not `TIdNotifier`) is in the `IdSync` unit.

Comment: Do you have this installed? [Hotfix 2 for Delphi, C++Builder and RAD Studio 2009](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40229): "*This hotfix addresses issues with debugging on Windows 7, including: - Assertion failure: "(!SetThreadContext failed")"*"

Comment: IdFtp1.Abort give rise to a Socket Error with message, "Connection reset by Peers". This is happening in the 1st method, using TThread.Queue.How to resolve this ?

Comment: Yeah, an example of what may happen when you answer a question that is not asked. @Priya - please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to get a hang of how the site works.